# Proof of involvement

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be two bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$.

$1)$ $\exists M>0,$ $\forall x\in H$ : $||A^{\ast}x|| \leq M||B^{\ast}x||,$ 
$2)$ $\exists C$ bounded operator on $H$ : $A=BC.$

We want to show that $1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $2$.

Assume that $1)$ is true. Now we define $D: R(B^{\ast})\longrightarrow R(A^{\ast})$ by $D(B^{\ast}f)=A^{\ast}f.$ 
$D$ is fine defined, and since $$||D(B^{\ast}f)||=||A^{\ast}f||\leq M||B^{\ast}f||. $$
$D$ admits a unique extension $\overline{D}:\overline{R(B^{\ast})}\longrightarrow R(A^{\ast}),$
and if we put $D=0$ on $R(B^{\ast})^{\perp},$ we will have $DB^{\ast}=A^{\ast},$ so $A=BD^{\ast}$ with $C=D^{\ast}.$ 
I don't understand why if we put $D= 0$ on $R(B^{\ast})^{\perp},$ we will have $DB^{\ast}=A^{\ast}?$ 
I tried to do as follows : if $f\in H$ so $B^{\ast}f\in R(B^{\ast})\subset H=\overline{R(B^{\ast})}\bigoplus R(B^{\ast})^{\perp}.$ So if $B^{\ast}f=B^{\ast}f_{1}+B^{\ast}f_{2}$ then, $DB^{\ast}f=DB^{\ast}f_{1}$ ......
\

**if anyone has an idea to help me, thanks !!!! **

Answer (score 1):

The equality $DB^*=A^*$ holds irrespective of whatever $D$ does on $(R(B^*)^\perp$. Indeed, for any $x\in H$ you have $B^*x\in R(B^*)$,
$$
DB^*x=\overline DB^*x=A^*x. 
$$
As this holds for any $x$, $DB^*=A^*$. The choice to make $D=0$ on $R(B^*)^\perp$ is the simplest one, there is no meaningful argument to justify another choice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. In this case what is the objective of the extension of $D$? why extend $D$ on $\overline {R(B^{\ast})}$

Comment: Because you want (from your question) "a bounded operator on $H$", not on a subspace.

Comment: okey , and if $\overline{R(B^{\ast})}$ is not dense on $H$?

Comment: You need to define $D$ on $(R(B^*)^\perp$, precisely what you describe in your question.

Comment: Normally, we have no interest in looking for the image of an element $t$ of $\overline{R(B^{\ast})}$ such that $t \notin R(B^{\ast}).$  because for all $f \in H$ we have $B^{\ast}f\in R(B^{\ast}).$ I understood things theoretically but I still feel that something is missing to show elementaryly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to see your problem. The statement in your question said "there exists a bounded opeartor $C$ on $H$..." If your operator is only defined on a subspace, it is not an operator on $H$.

Comment: I agree that we should extend $C$ over H. My problem concerns the way in which we are going to extend $C$. Normally the extension $\overline {D}$ is equal to $D$ only on $R(B^{\ast}).$ but on $\overline {R(B^{\ast})}$ ??

Comment: If your operator is linear and bounded, you don't get to choose how to extend to the closure, as the extension is unique.

Comment: we can always confuse $D$ with $\overline D$ ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "confuse".

Comment: instead of saying $\overline{D},$ we note it $D$

Comment: Yes. Since the extension is unique, having a particular notation for it does not usually bring much benefit. I guess it depends on the context. If you are precisely trying to prove that the extension exists, at that moment it is probably a good idea to use notation to distinguish both. Other than that, probably not.